# В чем разница? Window.onload

Tags: javascript

Если использовать

```
 window.onload = test();

        function test(){
            alert("Документ и все ресурсы загружены");
        }
```

то отображает сообщение.

Пробую

```
 window.onload = function() {
            alert( 'Документ и все ресурсы загружены' );
        };
```

не работает.

Почему?

Comment: без воспроизводимого примера - сложно сказать. возможно ты ошибся где-то пока писал  и в коде есть ошибка. Но пример рабочий

Comment: Сделайте эти две варианты на чистой странице и увидите что обе работают. дело в другом.

Comment: Второй код должен тоже работать.

Comment: ну 2рой вариант не сработает если его "запустить" после загрузки страницы :)

Comment: Кто-то успел написать: 
window.onload = function() {
  alert( 'Документ и все ресурсы загружены' );
}();  при таком коде заработало. Без скобок не работает

Comment: @АлександрАнтипов это неправильный вариант. он исполняет код моментально, а не дожидается загрузки ресурсов в окне. собственно код `window.onload = test();` обладает абсолютно  такой же ошибкой

Comment: Но тогда не понимаю, почему не работает: https://jsfiddle.net/qLbxoLj4/

Comment: @АлександрАнтипов потому что вы обработчик добавляете после срабатывания события `load`. А нужно это делать до: https://jsfiddle.net/qLbxoLj4/1/ . Если появится вопрос "а что изменилось-то?", то "JAVASCRIPT" -> "LOAD TYPE" -> "No wrap - in head".

Comment: @АлександрАнтипов а ещё вместо устаревшего `onload` стоит использовать `addEventListener("load"`.

Answer (score 3):

Это

```
window.onload = test();
```

не присваивание функции `test` в качества обработчика `onload`, а непосредственно вызов этой функции. Функция ничего не возвращает, то есть `onload`-у присваивается `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

Убери скобки после "test".
Когда ты присваиваешь обработчик событию ты не пишешь скобки.

window.onload = test; - вот так.

Когда ты пишешь со скобками ты вызываешь эту функцию.